# Why are changes to my page layout not reflecting in Communities delayed?

Tags: community, page-layout

I've noticed a weird bug in which changes to my Page Layout used in Communities for say New Contact Records are delayed.

An example of this is I have a Phone number field which is displayed on the page but not required, when marking this as required in my page layout editor no changes are reflected in the Community page, this is after I have have done a hard refresh and even logged out and logged back in.
Then when I removed the field from the layout editor, and refreshed my community page the field now appears (when it shouldn't) and has the required marked on the field.

Can anyone explain this weird behaviour?